# A question about "people reached"

Tags: support

The system tells me I have 'reached' about half a million people on EL&U in 21 months, which is quite a remarkable figure.

Can anyone tell me if this is done on the basis of IP addresses, that is to say does it tell me about 'readers' of EL&U who are not logged-in members ?

Or is it just a count of 'page-access' incidents from within EL&U by logged-in members of the site ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [**We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here),  the following snippet taken from the announcement posted December 2, 2014, shows that the data displayed is only an estimate

> > **Views of pages where your helpful posts had some decent probability of being seen.**
>
> That doesn't mean we *know* the visitor scrolled to your post, or that your answer helped them - we simply don't track that. But we should be able to estimate the likelihood of a given question or answer been seen as useful by viewers without enabling the 25th answer on an insanely popular post to get a lucky up-vote and credit all the views to the new author.
>
> That's how we got to the current method, which counts views on the following:
>
> - **Questions**
>
>   - Non-deleted only
> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

There are several SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer) [queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=People%20helped%20) available for those curious to find the *total number of views* any one person's contributions have generated. For example, this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/810217/people-helped-public-prototype-3) shows between 2011 and 2019,  [Barrie England's](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/12952/barrie-england) answers have *helped* a staggering **48,552,008** people/visitors.

Related: [What is "People helped" and why does it exist at all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[What's the formula for the "impact" figure on my user profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305316/whats-the-formula-for-the-impact-figure-on-my-user-profile-page)

Comment: Thank you. Appreciated.

Comment: One caution that may be worth noting in this regard is that the algorithm doesn't seem to be able to distinguish between page views that a question received before you posted your answer to an old question and page views that it received after you did so. A couple of months ago, one of my late-posted answers to a heavily visited old question either reached five upvotes or became one of the top three answers—and the algorithm suddenly awarded me 400,000 helped people. Gratifying, but hugely inaccurate.

Comment: @SvenYargs: So, to paraphrase Newton ... " If I have been seen a little further it is by standing on the shoulders of Giants."

Comment: @Robusto: For some reason, the fable of "[The Gnat and the Bull](http://www.read.gov/aesop/008.html)" springs to mind as well.